# Unable to Map list to Widgets

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

I am having a hard time determining why the "spread collections" is not "enabled" and understanding why my answer widgets are unable to call the data in the list. Also when I add the spread operator, my answer import is not recognized by Dart. Any assistance is appreciated.

Solutions attempted;

Executed "flutter upgrade" and restarted Visual Studio.
Accessed pubspec.yaml and updated flutter sdk from 2.0 to 2.6

[image: See Below Pic]

Comment: in your pubspec.yaml try to change your sdk for  ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

After changing the environment's sdk version in my pubspec.yaml file it stopped complaining for me:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"
```

You might also add a `analysis_options.yaml` file to the root of your project with the following content:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - spread-collections
```

Comment: I have already done that, saved the file, quit visual studio and restarted again. Didn't work for me